# MVC web.config Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the reason for this error and how to solve.

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens
>   when the site administrator has locked access to this section using
>   `<location allowOverride="false">` from an inherited configuration file.
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a hierarchy of config files that sets machine-level and then application-level restrictions over configuration sections.

If in your website you try to override one of the locked down sections up the hierarchy you will get this error.

For more information refer to these docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7#hierarchy